# Which material did the Vikings drink Mead from?

Tags: vikings, alcohol

I believe Vikings drank [Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead) as their common  alcoholic drink. If that is not right it doesn't really matter. Just replace Mead with whatever is right (beer, wine ...).

The question is what material did they use for their mugs to drink this drink out of? Perhaps it might be clay, wood or horn?

Note: I need the mug commonly used while partying or just sitting together on a table. If for example the "wilderness-mug" is different, it would be nice to know but it's not necessarily object of this question.

Comment: Given that the Vikings spread from their home countries into other territories over a period of a few hundred years, I would think it's unlikely that they can be considered a homogenous culture. Therefore, it's quite likely that they used a variety of drinking vessels made from a variety of materials.

Comment: @KillingTime That's why I used the word commonly. If we have found five times evidence for wood and three times evidence for horn the answer to this question would be wood.

Comment: English-speakers may be more familiar with the word "mead" rather than the German "Met"

Comment: @KillingTime - From the 9th to the 13th centuries, they all spoke the [same language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse) . For that period, they likely did have a fairly homogenous culture.

Comment: @bgwiehle - I'm going to edit with the assumption that's what he meant. If I'm wrong. revert it.

Comment: @T.E.D. They are generally synonymous.

Comment: @Benjamin - The issue is that I've never seen the word "Met" before, and hadn't a clue what it was supposed to be (other than short for "The Metropolitan Museum of Art" in NYC). As a consumable, [en.Wikipedia's best guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met) is that he was talking about Meth, which I'm pretty sure the Vikings didn't drink a lot of (although that would explain a lot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Horn. The [drinking horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_horn), known for centuries , was documented in use in several [Viking era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_horn#Viking_Age) sagas such as  the [Prose Edda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prose_Edda) and  [Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf).

[image: An 1893 depiction of the Norse goddess Sif holding a drinking horn.]

from wikipedia:

> Horn fragments of Viking Age drinking horns are only rarely preserved,
>   showing that both cattle and goat horns were in use, but the number of
>   decorative metal horn terminals and horn mounts recovered
>   archaeologically show that the drinking horn was much more widespread
>   than the small number of preserved horns would otherwise indicate

Not to say other technologies weren't available, this one would have been readily accessible from farmer on up to king.

The other answer,of course, is that the Viking drank from whatever he plundered.